# Safari's user agent: which WebKit version to trust?

Tags: safari, webkit, user-agent

I'm trying to extract not just the browser and its version number but also the rendering engine and its version number from common user-agent strings. Most browsers report this just fine, e.g.:

- "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; **Trident**/**4.0**)"
- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:**1.9.0.12**) **Gecko**/2009070611 Firefox/3.5.12"

Safari also reports the WebKit version number, but it seems to do so twice. Here's my own UA:

- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) **AppleWebKit**/**531.9** (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.3 Safari/**531.9.1**"

In this case, it seems that one is just more detailed than the other.

But when I look at databases of Safari UA strings, e.g. [useragentstring.com](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Safari/), the two versions are often entirely different.

- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/**532+** (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.2 Safari/**530.19.1**"
- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; cs-CZ) AppleWebKit/**525.28.3** (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.2.3 Safari/**525.29**"
- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/**530.19.2** (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.2 Safari/**530.19.1**"
- "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_4; en-us) AppleWebKit/**528.4+** (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0dp1 Safari/**526.11.2**"

Etc.

Which one do I use? It's not a major issue, but just wondering. Thanks!

Comment: To make matters worse, it has been made untrustworthy by design, so there’s no way to tell if it’s accurate (see [here](https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/pull/4470#issuecomment-534380837) and [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=180365)).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `AppleWebKit/xxx` section tells you which rendering engine is being used. The `Version/xxx Safari/xxx` section tells you which version of the "Browser Frontend" is being used.

[Webkit nightly builds](http://nightly.webkit.org/) run the currently installed Safari frontend with the latest nightly rendering engine doing the rendering. This is why you can get different `AppleWebKit/xxx` numbers with the same `Version/xxx Safari/xxx`.

Comment: What does Javascript functionality (e.g., XMLHttpRequest behavior) depend on, the rendering engine or "browser frontend"? I would assume this is part of the rendering engine (and thus AppleWebKit).

Comment: How does xxx part correspond to Safari version? or to anything?